# How to avoid automatic suggestions appearing in answer's comments?

Tags: discussion

I've seen this comment at rpg.se a couple of times:

> Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations. – Community

I guess a bot adds it. A suggestion to add "working code" is usually irrelevant in the context of TTRPG, unless we're talking about anydice or something like that. What factors cause the bot to add this line and how to avoid it?

Comment: [The fix for this was announced here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369272/674198)

Comment: But we can't flag the automod comments. The flag does not go through. @ThomasMarkov

Comment: @KorvinStarmast See [my feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369067/674198)

Comment: @ThomasMarkov I upvoted it; what's maddening is that going by what meta said we are supposed to be able to mark it as ' no longer needed' and that flag will go into the mod queue, but instead I get when I select that the flag of "this will go away when the post is corrected' and the flag cannot complete. Yes, this is me ranting: what were they thinking? Wait, they weren't thinking.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I still wonder what causes this, exactly. Does an answer have to be too short or what.

Comment: @enkryptor The community user comment is posted when a reviewer selects certain options during a first answer review.